# Are there any situations where EntityCollection<>.Attach is also useful with non-POCO entities?

Tags: entity-framework

FRom [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896408.aspx):

> The EntityCollection<>.Attach method is used to define a relationship
>   between an object and a related object when both objects are already
>   exist in the object context

Since with non-POCO entities relationships are automatically handled by Object Services, are `EntityCollection<>.Attach ( EntityReference<>.Attach )` only relevant with POCOs or are there also situations where they are useful even when using non-POCO entities?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Attach` function is also used to link entities to the context when they have been created outside the context.

Comment: ObjectContext.Attach is used to link entities to the context, but EntitCollection<>.Attach is used to define a relationship between related entities when both entities ALREADY EXIST in the object context